# Problems booting 12.04.2 after update

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, boot, upgrade, intel-graphics

I recently bought parts for a small mediacenter PC, and planned on running ubuntu with XBMC. I'm having massive problems with installing ubuntu and thinking about switching to windows (worst case).

The computer consists of following:
Intel Desktop Board DN2800MT Innovation Series
Corsair Mac Memory - 204 pin - 4 gb
Hatachi harddrive - 320 gb

At first i installed 12.10, without any luck, the system wasn't booting. After browsing the web, I installed the 12.04.1 LTS. That worked. After running til first update (to 12.04.2) the system won't boot properly (but not the same way, as with 12.10). It looks like this:

[image]

Can any of you guys help, so i don't have to use Windows.

Comment: When it boots and hits that point, can you hit "ctrl+alt+f1" to switch to a terminal and log in that way?

Comment: What is your graphics card? Or do you use an integrated Intel card? And sorry to say this, but it's probably just a bug and bugs are off-topic here on this site, as per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: +1 @IanN because that would say a lot about how to solve the problem and when/where the problem appears.  +1 ger because that would literally narrow down the problem. Nvidia prob? Ati prob? Intel misconfiguration prob?